# Proving $dim(V_{1})+dim(V_{2})-dim(V_{1}\cap V_{2})=dim(V_{1}+V_{2})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ be finite dimensional subspaces of a vector space V.

Suppose {$\overrightarrow x_{1},...,\overrightarrow x_{k}$} is a basis for $V_{1}\cap V_{2}$.

We can extend that basis to a basis {$\overrightarrow x_{1},...,\overrightarrow x_{k},\overrightarrow y_{1},...,\overrightarrow y_{l}$} for $V_{1}$ with $\overrightarrow y_{i} \not \in Span(\overrightarrow x_{1},...,\overrightarrow x_{k},y_{1},...,y_{i-1}$) $1\le i\le l$

We can also extend it to a basis {$\overrightarrow x_{1},...,\overrightarrow x_{k},\overrightarrow z_{1},...,\overrightarrow z_{m}$} for $V_{2}$ with $\overrightarrow z_{i} \not \in Span(\overrightarrow x_{1},...,\overrightarrow x_{k},z_{1},...,z_{i-1}$} $1\le i\le m$

Since $V_{1}+V_{2}=Span(V_{1}\cup V_{2})$, all we need to prove is that the set $V_{1}\cup V_{2}$={$\overrightarrow x_{1},...,\overrightarrow x_{k},\overrightarrow y_{1},..,\overrightarrow y_{l},\overrightarrow z_{1},...,\overrightarrow z_{m}$} is linearly independent so that it becomes a basis for $V_{1}+V_{2}$ and proving the equation of the title would be easy. How do I prove that the set is linearly independent?

Comment: Or isomorphism theorem: $\left(V_1+V_2\right)/V_2\cong V_1/\left(V_1\cap V_2\right)$.

Comment: @Batominovski, I never took that theorem, does it help with linear independence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $0=\sum (\alpha_ix_i+\beta_iy_i+\gamma_iz_i)\to -\sum \gamma_i z_i= \sum (\alpha_ix_i+\beta_iy_i)$.

Now, LRS$\in V_2$ and RRS$\in V_1$ and then $ -\sum \gamma_i z_i\in V_1\cap V_2\to \sum \beta_i y_i \in V_1\cap V_2\to \beta_i=0$ for all $i$.

Now, replacing in the first equation, then $0=\sum (\alpha_ix_i+\gamma_iz_i)$ and all coefficients must be zero because $\{x_i,z_i}\}$ are basis of $V_2$.

Comment: I don't understand the implications in the second line, cold you elaborate please?

Comment: If \sum beta_iy_i \in V1\cap V2 must be zero, because x_i's are basis of V1\cap V2 and y_i's and x_i's are li

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.